# Using .html to automate folders opening

Tags: html, animation, automation, hyperlink

I am looking to create an animated html website where it automates what it is like to open basic folders found in Windows/MACOS. I was wondering the best way to do this? The idea is that you arrive at the first page of the website, click on a folder, and it continuously keeps on opening more folder without user doing anything.

Thanks

Comment: It keeps opening actual folders found on the end user's machine?  If that's the case it's a security issue and isn't possible.

Comment: No, I will create a bunch of folders inside of folders on my own .html site, it will simply autorun the clicking of those folders.